# String with non-literal complex numbers to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, matrix

I'd like to take a string like this

`A = '[[complex(1,-1), complex(1,1)], [1, 1]]'`

and transform it into this numpy array

```
array([[1.-1.j, 1.+1.j],
   [1.+0.j, 1.+0.j]])
```

I have tried using this code

```
string = a.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"",  "").replace(" ","")
np.fromstring(string, dtype=complex, count=-1, sep=',')
```

but the output is this

```
array([], dtype=complex128)
```

if there is at least an easy way to put the matrix A into this form

```
A = '1-1j, 1+1j, 1, 1'
```

the code above works. I need to do this with a lot of matrices imported from .csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must resist the temptation to use `eval`, because [`eval` is unsafe and a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It [really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). If you can be sure that the input is safe because you're controlling the input: change the output of the previous step so that you don't have to use `eval` in the first place.

Since your use case is very specific (`complex(a, b)` where neither `a` nor `b` can contain any commas nor parentheses) it's easy to write a regex pattern that will help replace your complex calls with complex literals. Once we have that we can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to perform a *safe* conversion from string to numbers which you can feed numpy.

See the following few definitions:

```py
import ast
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'complex\(([^)]+),([^)]+)\)') 

def complex_from_match(match): 
    """Converts a regex match containing 'complex(a, b)' to a complex number""" 
    re = float(match.group(1)) 
    im = float(match.group(2)) 
    return re + 1j*im 

def literalify_complex(s): 
    """Converts a string with a number of the form complex(a, b) into a string literal"""

    return pattern.sub(lambda match: repr(complex_from_match(match)), s)
```

Here `pattern` is a regex pattern that matches substring of the form `complex(a, b)`. For each match `match.group(1)` gives us `a` and `match.group(2)` gives `b`.

The function `literalify_complex(s)` calls `pattern.sub` on the input string `s`, which will call the passed callable (a lambda) on every match for the pattern `pattern` in `s`. The lambda I defined makes use of the `complex_from_match` function which takes the matched string `complex(a,b)` and effectively turns it into the native python complex number `a + 1j*b`. Then this complex number is converted into its `repr` during replacement, effectively turning things like `complex(1, 3.4)` into `1+3.4j`. Here's what the output looks like:

```py
>>> literalify_complex('[[complex(1,-1), complex(1,1)], [1, 1]]')
'[[(1-1j), (1+1j)], [1, 1]]'

>>> literalify_complex('[[complex(0,-3.14), complex(1.57337537832783243243,1e-100)], [1, 1]]')
'[[-3.14j, (1.5733753783278324+1e-100j)], [1, 1]]'
```

These are now strings that can directly be converted to nested python lists using `literal_eval`:

```py
>>> ast.literal_eval(literalify_complex('[[complex(1,-1), complex(1,1)], [1, 1]]'))
[[(1-1j), (1+1j)], [1, 1]]
```

And then these lists can be passed to numpy:

```py
def crazy_complex_string_to_ndarray(s): 
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(literalify_complex(s)))

# >>> crazy_complex_string_to_ndarray('[[complex(1,-1), complex(1,1)], [1, 1]]')
# array([[1.-1.j, 1.+1.j],
#        [1.+0.j, 1.+0.j]])
#
# >>> crazy_complex_string_to_ndarray('[[complex(0,-3.14),  complex(1.57337537832783243243,1e-100)], [1, 1]]')
# array([[-0.        -3.14e+000j,  1.57337538+1.00e-100j],
#        [ 1.        +0.00e+000j,  1.        +0.00e+000j]])
```

The nice thing about this approach is that any kind of malformed or malicious input will loudly fail (during the `ast.literal_eval` step), rather than giving unexpected or harmful results.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware about the risks of using eval(). This is a great answer, thanks!